# Keyboard Mapping in .NET

Tags: .net, keyboard

If I know that a certain key has been pressed (eg `Key.D3`), and that the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is also down (`Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift)`), how can I find out what character that refers to (eg, <kbd>#</kbd> on US keyboard, UK pound sign on UK keyboard, etc)?

Put another way, how can I find out, programatically, that <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> produces <kbd>#</kbd> (it wouldn't on a non-US keyboard).

Comment: Updated my answer with solution, cheers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to determine what character you will get from a given key with given modifiers, you should use the [`user32 ToAscii`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646316.aspx) function. Or [`ToAsciiEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646318.aspx) if you want to use a keyboard layout *other* then the current one.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public static class User32Interop
{
  public static char ToAscii(Keys key, Keys modifiers)
  {
    var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder(2);
    int result = ToAscii((uint)key, 0, GetKeyState(modifiers),
                         outputBuilder, 0);
    if (result == 1)
      return outputBuilder[0];
    else
      throw new Exception("Invalid key");
  }

  private const byte HighBit = 0x80;
  private static byte[] GetKeyState(Keys modifiers)
  {
    var keyState = new byte[256];
    foreach (Keys key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
    {
      if ((modifiers & key) == key)
      {
        keyState[(int)key] = HighBit;
      }
    }
    return keyState;
  }

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern int ToAscii(uint uVirtKey, uint uScanCode,
                                    byte[] lpKeyState,
                                    [Out] StringBuilder lpChar,
                                    uint uFlags);
}
```

You can now use it like this:

```
char c = User32Interop.ToAscii(Keys.D3, Keys.ShiftKey); // = '#'
```

If you need more than one modifier, just `or` them. `Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.AltKey`

Comment: Yes, but WHY? (Don't answer that).  How can I find out, programatically, that Shift + Key.D3 produces '#' (it wouldn't on a non-US keyboard).

Comment: Oh, perhaps you should refine your question to make that point clear.

Comment: Found a solution, let me change answer

Comment: That looks like a winner!  Thanks.

Comment: Well, I'd imagine it's not a very used function and was not a priority for the WinForms team to wrap. At least you can always PInvoke Win32 code.