# .net Keys Enumeration ToString() working with BackSlash '\'

Tags: c#, .net, keypress, tostring, key

I have an event handling a keypress (KeyDown) that has **KeyEventArgs** argument.  This class has a few relevant members:

- KeyCode
- KeyData
- KeyValue

My problem is: *Whenever I press BackSlash, I'd like to get a String with the single character "\".*

Whenever I call ToString() on any of the above characters, it just returns **Oem5**.

I know I could just throw it in a giant if clause, but I'd like to avoid that if I can.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you get with `(char)KeyCode`?

Comment: try [KeyConverter.ConvertToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyconverter.converttostring.aspx)

Comment: As per the (char)KeyCode, I get "Ȕ"

Comment: @paolo, unfortunately, I'm operating under WinForms .net 2.0 (C++), and I don't have access to the System.Windows.Input.KeyConverter class, I'm searching for a similar alternative.

Comment: @greggorob64 with the KeyPress event you could try the KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar property

Comment: I'm going to try the KeyPress event.  The KeyConverter.ToString just throws an exception. (using all 3 of they key* arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Keyboard Mapping in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728477/keyboard-mapping-in-net) provides an answer, though it may be easier to use the KeyPress event than KeyDown. KeyDown works at the level of abstraction of the actual keyboard (bunch of keys, will differ according to locale and set-up and may have e.g. a two different sets of numbers, which you may wish to distinguish, and there may not even be a character if the key is a modifier or dead-accent key). KeyPress is better-equipped to deal with the level of abstraction of actual characters being input.

Comment: KeyPress ended up working best off all the answers.  KeyChar had exactly what I was looking for.  It is a pain in the butt through, because it doesn't handle function keys.  I have to use a compbination of both keypress and keydown to handle all of my keys now.  Thanks!