# C# Keyboard mappings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard

I am trying to create an on screen keyboard in WPF, however I've gotten stuck on a programatic way to map the non-alpha keys to their shifted equivalent, for example:

1 becomes !
2 becomes "
3 becomes £

etc, for if possible, the current culture, or if not the UK Layout.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: How are you handling the alphanumeric keys?

Comment: I am handling the alpha keys by just doing char.ToUpper, not alphanumeric since numerics don't map like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to interrogate the keyboard map as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728477/keyboard-mapping-in-net).

This way you can get the charachter for all modifiers on your current map or another map.

The post describes how to use the [`ToAscii`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646316.aspx) WinAPI, you can use the results to "modify" the display of your keyboard. Use `ToAsciiEx` for other keyboard maps.

This doesen't help you with what I think is a rather more difficult problem of how to layout the keyboard, touched on by this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards).

However, if you are going for a standardised tablet friendly approach you have probably dealt with this and, in fact, the localization of the user may be irrelavent.