# Difficulty processing Swiss keyboard '+'

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, keyboard

I'm working on a project at work and I'm a bit stumped. We have a graphical display which processes keyboard input and zooms in on a display when either the `+` on the numpad or the `+` above the equals key are pressed. It works nicely on most computers, but on a Swiss (German) layout, the `+` key is instead `Shift+1`. We are currently using `OnKeyDown`, which returns the key value which is pressed (The '1' key value of 49 if I'm trying to handle the Swiss `+`) as well as boolean variables indicating whether the shift, control, and alt keys are pressed. I've looked at using OnKeyPress, but I seem to lose the ability to check whether the Control key is pressed there.

I may have a potential solution at [how to capture the '#' character on different locale keyboards in WPF/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825820/how-to-capture-the-character-on-different-locale-keyboards-in-wpf-c/5826175#5826175), but pulling in external DLLs to properly localize a keyboard to use the `+` key the same no matter what language the keyboard is set to seems dreadfully inelegant. I'd like to believe that, since 2012, Microsoft has added something native to the C# language to process keyboard input in foreign layouts without jumping through hoops.

Worse comes to worse, I can always detect which keyboard layout is being used and handle this as a special case, but that seems to be a last-resort kind of thing.

The code at [Keyboard Mapping in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728477/keyboard-mapping-in-net/728496#728496) is slightly more useful, but it's got some brittle bits to it, like accessing an array outside of its boundaries if it gets `Keys.Shift` instead of `Keys.ShiftKey`, and it still requires pulling in the outside DLL. Is this really something that Microsoft find unimportant?

*Edit*: I think that I have it working with the code from above about "Keyboard Mapping in .NET". I'm getting the correct values for all of the keys accessed by pressing shift and a key. I'm a bit worried that I'm going to miss some other case involving adding Control or Alt to it, but it functions. I would still prefer a more elegant solution.

**Further Edit**: The technique at [Get the char on Control.KeyDown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830498/get-the-char-on-control-keydown/3831027#3831027) also works for a given control.

***Later Edit***: Right. It functions as it ought to, but it looks like my error was always something simpler. The non-numpad "plus" should always map to `Keys.Oemplus` for the KeyCode in the event no matter what button press triggers it. It doesn't for the Swiss keyboard and possibly others that I've yet to find. Interesting. I have no idea where I would even report that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I went with the code at [How to convert a virtual-key code to a character according to the current keyboard layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929275/how-to-convert-a-virtual-key-code-to-a-character-according-to-the-current-keyboa/6949520#6949520). I still think that this should be easier to build into the code, but it should suffice for now.

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern int ToUnicode(
      uint wVirtKey,
      uint wScanCode,
      byte[] lpKeyState,
      [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeParamIndex = 4)] 
        StringBuilder pwszBuff,
      int cchBuff,
      uint wFlags);

  static string GetCharsFromKeys(Keys keys, bool shift, bool altGr)
  {
     var buf = new StringBuilder(256);
     var keyboardState = new byte[256];
     if (shift)
        keyboardState[(int)Keys.ShiftKey] = 0xff;
     if (altGr)
     {
        keyboardState[(int)Keys.ControlKey] = 0xff;
        keyboardState[(int)Keys.Menu] = 0xff;
     }
     ToUnicode((uint)keys, 0, keyboardState, buf, 256, 0);
     return buf.ToString();
  }
```